# How to extract Outlook email data from a specific sender in date and time sequence?

Tags: vba, sorting, datetime, email, outlook

I extract data from Outlook email into Excel. The data is not extracted in sequence based on date and time.

The date format in my computer is ddmmyyyy format and the time zone is UK.

I want the date to be in one column and the time to be in another column.
Also I want to extract the email from sender email jkcopy@gmail.com.

```vb
Sub GetMailInfo()

Dim results() As String

' get contacts
results = ExportEmails(True)

' paste onto worksheet
Range(Cells(1, 1), Cells(UBound(results), UBound(results, 2))).Value = results

MsgBox "Completed"
End Sub


Function ExportEmails(Optional headerRow As Boolean = False) As String()

Dim objOutlook As Object ' Outlook.Application
Dim objNamespace As Object ' Outlook.Namespace
Dim strFolderName As Object
Dim objMailbox As Object
Dim objFolder As Object
Dim mailFolderItems As Object ' Outlook.items
Dim folderItem As Object
Dim msg As Object ' Outlook.MailItem
Dim tempString() As String
Dim i As Long
Dim numRows As Long
Dim startRow As Long
Dim jAttach As Long ' counter for attachments
Dim debugMsg As Integer

' select output results worksheet and clear previous results
Sheets("Outlook Results").Select
Sheets("Outlook Results").Cells.ClearContents
Range("A1").Select

Set objOutlook = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
'MsgBox objOutlook, vbOKOnly 'for debugging
Set objNamespace = objOutlook.GetNamespace("MAPI")
'MsgBox objNamespace, vbOKOnly 'for debugging
'Set objInbox = objNamespace.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
'MsgBox objInbox, vbOKOnly 'for debugging
Set strFolderName = objNamespace.PickFolder
Set mailFolderItems = strFolderName.Items

' if calling procedure wants header row
If headerRow Then
    startRow = 1
Else
    startRow = 0
End If

numRows = mailFolderItems.Count

' resize array
ReDim tempString(1 To (numRows + startRow), 1 To 100)

' loop through folder items
For i = 1 To numRows
    Set folderItem = mailFolderItems.Item(i)

    If IsMail(folderItem) Then
        Set msg = folderItem
    End If

    With msg
        tempString(i + startRow, 1) = .SenderName
        tempString(i + startRow, 2) = .ReceivedTime
        tempString(i + startRow, 3) = .Subject
        'tempString(i + startRow, 4) = Left$(.Body, 200)  ' throws error without limit
        'tempString(i + startRow, 5) = .SenderEmailAddress
        'tempString(i + startRow, 6) = .SentOn

    End With

    ' adding file attachment names where they exist - added by JP
    If msg.Attachments.Count > 50 Then

        For jAttach = 1 To msg.Attachments.Count
            tempString(i + startRow, 39 + jAttach) = msg.Attachments.Item(jAttach).DisplayName
        Next jAttach

    End If

Next i

' first row of array should be header values
If headerRow Then

    tempString(1, 1) = "SenderName"
    tempString(1, 2) = "ReceivedTime"
    tempString(1, 3) = "subject"
    'tempString(1, 4) = "Body"
    'tempString(1, 5) = "SenderEmailAddress"
    'tempString(1, 6) = "SentOn"
End If

ExportEmails = tempString

' apply pane freeze and filtering

Range("A2").Select
ActiveWindow.FreezePanes = True
Rows("1:1").Select

'Selection.AutoFilter

End Function


Function IsMail(itm As Object) As Boolean
IsMail = (TypeName(itm) = "MailItem")
End Function
```

Answer (score 1):

The date/time format does not matter as long as you are adding the data as the `DateTime` type, not as a string (you do that part correctly).

If you want a particular order, you can either resort the data later in Excel, or you can sort the `Items` collection first by calling [Items.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.sort)

```
Set mailFolderItems = strFolderName.Items
mailFolderItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", false
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to sort the items collections before iterating over all entries. The [Items.Sort](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.items.sort) method sorts the collection of items by the specified property. The index for the collection is reset to 1 upon completion of this method.

The [MailItem.ReceivedTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/outlook.mailitem.receivedtime)
which returns a `Date` indicating the date and time at which the item was received property can be used for sorting items in the folder.

```
mailFolderItems.Sort "[ReceivedTime]", False 

' loop through folder items
For i = 1 To numRows
  Set folderItem = mailFolderItems.Item(i)
```

Use the [FormatDateTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/formatdatetime-function) function which returns an expression formatted as a date or time for your cells/rows.